# AEM/CQ5 Request Parameter not UTF-8

Tags: aem

Have a slight issue with AEM 6.0 SP1 and the search component.   If searching for a french word like `"Français"`   the `"ç"` gets messed up

the query string is like `?q=Français` 
on the JSP side, `request.getCharacterEncoding()` returns *ISO-8859-1* instead of *UTF-8* like we need.

I know that when under tomcat you can change the `URIEncoding` at the connector level.

But for an AEM/CQ instance running directly by itself, there is no such thing.
Anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**For 5.6.1** : The default encoding can be set in the configuration of **Apache Sling Main Servlet** . In the Configuration Manager 
(<domain>:<port>/system/console/configMgr) look for Apache Sling Main Servlet and configure **Default Parameter Encoding** property.

[image]

**For 6.0** (credits - [Francois Cournoyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3307907/francois-cournoyer)) : The configuration has been moved to **Apache Sling Request Parameter Handling**

Configure **Temporary File Location** to point to an absolute path in case of errors while saving the configuration

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, from what I can see, the Default Parameter Encoding is gone in AEM 6.0 SP1!  Sling Engine Implementation Version 2.3.3.R1588174

the last param in the config is Recorded Request Path Pattern now

Comment: After looking into it, there is now a Apache Sling Request Parameter Handling where the Default Param Encoding resides, but it's currently bugged out because when you try to save, it produces a nullpointer error.

Comment: To avoid the Null Pointer you need to also specify an absolute path for the "Temporary File Location".  Then it works fine.  I'll accept your answer anyway since it pushed me to the right info and if other ask for it, they'll see my comments for AEM 6.0 SP1/SP2

Comment: @FrancoisCournoyer , in AEM 6.0 (No SP's) , there is no error when saving for me. Have updated the answer with details for 6.0.

Comment: Looks like it's something that crept up in SP1, and wasn't fixed in SP2.  http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__8ieg-hi_i_set_theosg.html   They seem aware of it at least.  The error doesn't show in the OSGI console when saving, it'll show in the error.log, it still saves.  But will not use the UTF-8 encoding unless you add the temp location

Answer (score 1):

For forms within CQ always have a hidden field with the charset set to UTF-8 or the charset of your HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="UTF-8"/>
```

This will ensure proper encoding when the servlet retrieves the post.

Comment: This was for the Search component, which relies on "GET" parameters, having the _charset_ appear in the url wasn't really ok with the client.  Sling lets you decide the charset you're expecting in the OSGI configuration, it's cleaner that way.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Need to add the Default charset change as part of response header.
Here is the detailed process

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr
 -->Apache Sling Main Servlet 
    -->     Additional response headers add the below entry
                 Content-Type=text/html;charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Except that this is for response headers, the issue wasn't what came from the server, but what came from the browser. Which is through the Apache Sling Request Handler.  Response header affect what goes out, not in.