# How to set the default character encoding in AEM/Sling?

Tags: encoding, aem, sling

I'm trying to set the character encoding in use by AEM/Sling to UTF-8. According to the [Sling documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/request-parameters.html#character-encoding), this can be overridden by a property on the **Sling Main Servlet:**

> As of Sling Engine 2.2.4 the `_charset_` request parameter is optional.
>   As of this version the Sling Main Servlet supports a configuration
>   setting which allows to change the default character encoding used if
>   the `_charset_` request parameter is missing.
>
> **To enable this functionality set the `sling.default.parameter.encoding` parameter of the Sling Main Servlet (PID `org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet`)** configuration to the
>   desired encoding, which of course must be supported by the actual Java
>   Platform.

But while this was possible in previous versions, this configuration seems to have been removed from the latest versions of AEM (6.0+) and Sling (8), i.e. in the menu at

- http://localhost:8080/system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet?post=false

the `sling.default.parameter.encoding` isn't present anymore. Is there an alternative way to configure this value now, to use UTF-8 rather than the ISO default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AEM/CQ5 Request Parameter not UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842990/aem-cq5-request-parameter-not-utf-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is moved to **Apache Sling Request Parameter Handling** on AEM 6.0

Comment: And the PID of that configuration is org.apache.sling.engine.parameters - the SlingMainServlet did output a confusing warning message about this, that's now fixed by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-5370